# Why do CUDA 6.5 examples not work with CUDA 5.5?

Tags: linux, cuda

I have CUDA version I have is 5.5 as evidenced by the output of `nvcc` which is:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2013 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_17_18:36:13_PDT_2013
Cuda compilation tools, release 5.5, V5.5.0
```

I am not yet using 6.5 since my NVIDIA driver is 331.113 (it is the Kubuntu 14.04 repo version which is how I installed everything).

I got the 6.5 examples and, for example, if I make the `2_graphics/Mandelbrot` example, there are no compilation errors but when I run it, I get

```
[CUDA Mandelbrot/Julia Set] - Starting...
CUDA error at ../../common/inc/helper_cuda.h:1032 code=35(cudaErrorInsufficientDriver) "cudaGetDeviceCount(&device_count)"
```

Now, if I just go into the `examples/5.5/2_graphics/Mandelbrot` directory and `make` the code, when I run it everything works fine.

What is happening when I get the `cudaErrorInsufficientDriver` error and what is the difference between these two `Mandelbrot` packages that would cause this error but not cause a compilation error?

Comment: There error code displayed is quite clear: The CUDA 6.5 runtime requires a CUDA driver that is more recent than what you have installed. If you install a more recent driver suitable for CUDA 6.5, you can run apps built from CUDA 6.5 and CUDA 5.5

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that is what the error is saying. I'm confused as to what (in the source code or compilation) is causing this since both `/6.5/*/Mandelbrot` and `/5.5/*/Mandelbrot` do the exact same thing.

Comment: When you build using CUDA 6.5, the executables are linked to the CUDA 6.5 runtime, which requires something like driver 343.19. When you build using CUDA 5.5 the executable are linked to the 5.5 runtime. The difference is not in the apps, it is in the CUDA runtime linked into the binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app that you ran: `2_graphics/Mandelbrot` was apparently compiled with CUDA 6.5 *tools*, i.e. `nvcc`, and most importantly it was linked against the CUDA 6.5 runtime library (cudart).

This library will, at initialization, check the driver version that is currently installed.  If it is not a sufficient driver for CUDA 6.5, it will return an error on CUDA API calls.

If you had *only* CUDA 5.5 installed, and built the `2_graphics/Mandelbrot` sample code only with CUDA 5.5 tools and libraries (even if the sample code itself came from the CUDA 6.5 distribution) most likely it would just work.